# What does the with-bindings option do in brew?

Tags: homebrew

I'm looking to brew a package (graphviz) and see it has one option—amid others—

```
--with-bindings
   Build Perl/Python/Ruby/etc. bindings
```

I might want that, if only I knew what it means...?

What might `with-bindings` mean and why, or why not, would I want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings is a term used for the API to access a library or tool through a particular programming language. In this case, it's saying that the Graphviz package has bindings for Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. programs to be able to generate graphs.

If all you want to do is use Graphviz on its own, you don't need to install the bindings.

Comment: Thx. Personally I did want the bindings (use with pygraphviz). Luckily the 'poured from bottle' seems to have with-bindings option set, so it works out of the bottle.  I'm a little curious to try without the option just to confirm difference it makes a difference, but not worth the risk/pain.